# How the rails find the controller from routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning rails. I would like to check the convention here,

say, if I have a comment resource, will the rails always to find action in the comments_controller, no matter the rource is independent or nested in another resource?

A:

```
resources :comments
```

B:

```
resources :blogs do
    resources :comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will always use `CommentsController`. But using nested resources you will also have the `blog_id` set in `params`. You can read more on here, with detailed description and examples: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources